# This declaration shadows an existing declaration

Tags: solidity, truffle

When i try to run migration from truffle, i got this problem, here my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

  contract DappToken {

    uint256 public totalSupply;

    function DappToken () public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }
   }
```

And I got this message on cmd window, seem there are many more issue, so if you guy could help me out, i really appreaciated.

[image: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.]

PS: for more infomation, I follow the instruction video "Code Your Own Cryptocurrency on Ethereum (Full)" from Dapp University chanel on youtube , at 37:40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version `0.4.22` of Solidity, the constructor isn't the contract's name anymore but `constructor`.

Read more [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#constructor).

Comment: I try again and change the name of function, it's work, thanks !